# Ubuntu Applications Icon bug

Tags: 22.04, icons, desktop-icons

Is this a known bug?
[image]

[image]

If I click on the icons I see the rotating wheel but nothing happens.
If I click "Show details" both open the app on the "Software" App, Spotify shows with Ubuntu Snap source and needed to be installed (but I already have Spotify), Slack opens the  Flathub source showing that it is already installed.

Comment: Issues can occur for many reasons, have you tried starting the *app* from the CLI or command line, as messages appear at the terminal which are usually really helpful.  There have been some recent bugs I've noted that your post reminds me of (*all occurred after specific events which you don't mention*), but your post contains too little detail to be specific.

Comment: "*Is this a known bug?*" Seems like you are asking us to simply check the bug trackers for you. Is this something you are incapable of doing yourself due to, say, disability? Alternately, if you are asking for troubleshooting assistance with your two different Spotify packages, please edit your question to clearly say so.